# Get form id in jquery Mobile 'pageshow'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

How can I get form id of the current page in 'pageshow' of Jquery Mobile? I'm able to get the id of the current active page in this way.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function () {
var id = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id'); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function () {
    var formID = $.mobile.activePage.find('form').attr('id'); 
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/CEAwG/

Comment: that code is returning 'undefined' inside pageshow, your working example is using 'pagebeforeshow', can you show an example for 'pageshow'

Comment: Same code works also for the pageshow, just change it in my example. Can you add an example of your page? Also are you sure your form has an id? First test it to see if your form really exist: alert($.mobile.activePage.find('form').html());

Comment: yeah sorry, it works. My hoem page did not have a form. Thanks sir!